# read float values from ASCII file with variable number of columns

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I Have ASCII files containing floating point numbers. Most rows have 10 columns, but some rows have less columns.  An example is this:

```
* lat =   33.2813
  19.61  19.92  21.82  21.94  22.77  25.81  29.48  29.86  29.92  28.98
  27.94  25.78  23.68  23.37
* lat =   33.3438
  20.16  23.62  27.73  31.12  33.06  34.01  35.78  37.03  37.79  35.74
  34.12  31.83  33.98  28.57
* lat =   33.4063
  28.26  30.04  35.00  37.92  41.50  44.55  45.44  46.74  46.74  43.47
  37.67  35.67  35.67  31.64
* lat =   33.4688
  34.02  36.07  38.95  44.24  46.49  47.98  50.62  51.95  51.95  51.95
  48.31  41.03  38.01  34.58
* lat =   33.5313
  36.94  37.12  44.04  48.41  51.70  52.71  54.18  55.71  56.98  62.10
  57.26  49.05  44.18  41.50
```

The rows starting with `*` are comments.

How can I read this file efficiently using numpy?  (this is a toy example; my actual data files have >> 1E6 values in them).  The numpy functions loadtxt / genfromtxt don't seem to cope with the variable number of columns:

```
   In [25]: np.loadtxt(fn, comments="*", dtype=float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2419eebb6114> in <module>()
----> 1 np.loadtxt(fn, comments="*", dtype=float)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
    833             fh.close()
    834 
--> 835     X = np.array(X, dtype)
    836     # Multicolumn data are returned with shape (1, N, M), i.e.
    837     # (1, 1, M) for a single row - remove the singleton dimension there

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

genfromtxt is more verbose, but doesn't work either:

```
    In [27]: np.genfromtxt(fn, comments="*", dtype=float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-6c6e8879e4b9> in <module>()
----> 1 np.genfromtxt(fn, comments="*", dtype=float)

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skiprows, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise)
   1636             # Raise an exception ?
   1637             if invalid_raise:
-> 1638                 raise ValueError(errmsg)
   1639             # Issue a warning ?
   1640             else:

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #5 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #8 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #11 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #14 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #17 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #20 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #23 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #26 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
    Line #29 (got 4 columns instead of 10)
```

there seems to be a kwarg `invalid_raise`, but setting this to `False` leads to the rows with less than 10 values being ignored.

I'd appreciate any help in getting this solved.  I'd be happy to write my own file parser in Cython, but wasn't really able to find information on efficient string->float conversion in Cython ...

Comment: If the lines with `*` are just comments, then they shouldn't be used to delimit different arrays. It seems like they are not comments, but rather they are delimiters that indicate the next start of some values. Otherwise, why wouldn't you just use a generator over the file, skipping `*` lines, and appending data to one big array?

Comment: In other words, are you going to need the `lat` values from your `*` lines to do any organization, filtering, processing, etc., of the values listed below it? If not ever, then why are the values kept separately? If yes, then you need a different data structure, like a Pandas DataFrame, record array, or dict, that associates the `lat` value with its array of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) parser.  If you just want the numpy arrays, take `df.values`

```
In [239]: import pandas as pd

In [240]: df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', header=None, skiprows=1, delim_whitespace=True)

In [242]: df = df[df[0] != '*']  #filter out comment rows

In [245]: df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [246]: df
Out[246]: 
        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
0   19.61  19.92  21.82  21.94  22.77  25.81  29.48  29.86  29.92  28.98
1   27.94  25.78  23.68  23.37    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3   20.16  23.62  27.73  31.12  33.06  34.01  35.78  37.03  37.79  35.74
4   34.12  31.83  33.98  28.57    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
6   28.26  30.04  35.00  37.92  41.50  44.55  45.44  46.74  46.74  43.47
7   37.67  35.67  35.67  31.64    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
9   34.02  36.07  38.95  44.24  46.49  47.98  50.62  51.95  51.95  51.95
10  48.31  41.03  38.01  34.58    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
12  36.94  37.12  44.04  48.41  51.70  52.71  54.18  55.71  56.98  62.10
13  57.26  49.05  44.18  41.50    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```